# how to convert binary string to hex and send over Uart Port in java

Tags: java, string, hex, byte

I have a binary string which look like this 11001111 00011111 11111111 and want to convert this to hex and sent over Uart to Arduino. 
How can I can convert each 8 bit to hex without getting signed values as byte data type does not support values above than 128.

I am doing this

```
string b = "110011110001111111111111"
byte[] bval = new BigInteger(b, 2).toByteArray();
```

Expected Output: cf1fff

Since all these bits corresponds to some data change in data changes the behavior in the receiver side.
Please tell me where I'm getting wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String b = "110011110001111111111111";

int decimal=Integer.parseInt(b,2);

String t = Integer.toHexString(decimal);

byte[] bval = t.getBytes();
```

Comment: for this string = 110010001001010000000100000000000000000000000000 I am getting number format exception how to resolve this?

Comment: Change int to long or big integer if your number is very high/big

Comment: It worked. But I have one doubt for hex string = {c89484000000}; the byte array outpuut is = {99,56,57,52,56,52,48,48,48,48}; for this  binary string = "110010001001010000000100000000000000000000000000" and therefore I am getting wrong value in Receiving side.

Comment: change your array and int variable to long. its going beyond limit.

Comment: and if this answer helped you, please upvote and accept answer.

Comment: I'm doing this now long decimal=Long.parseLong(b,2);

        String t = Long.toHexString(decimal);
        System.out.println(t);

        byte[] bval = t.getBytes();  and for this I'm getting such bytes

Comment: Output is {99, 56, 57, 52, 48, 52, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48}

Comment: So, the problem is getBytes() is giving me ASCII value for each character in string t. I dont want that I want to send hex as it is